# VBA- Modify Calculated Field in each sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am able to run my VBA script through each tab and apply pivot table functions. However, I am struggling with out to modify an existing Calculated Field in the pivot tables. How does one modify an existing Calculated Field in each pivot table of each worksheet of a workbook?

I've placed asterisks where I've added the VBA code that I'm trying to implement (I realize it doesn't work currently).

```
Sub DEG()

Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim aWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim pvt As Excel.PivotTable
Dim myPivotField As Excel.PivotField
**Dim myCalcField As Excel.CalculatedFields
        Set aWB = ActiveWorkbook
        For Each WS In aWB.Worksheets

            For Each pvt In WS.PivotTables

        Set myPivotField = Nothing
        **Set myCalcField = Nothing

        On Error Resume Next

        Set myPivotField = pvt.PivotFields("Convert or Convert with DEG")

        myPivotField.CurrentPage = "Y"

        Set myPivotField = pvt.PivotFields("Select2")

        myPivotField.CurrentPage = "1"

        Set myPivotField = pvt.PivotFields("Top 20")

        myPivotField.CurrentPage = "Y"

        **Set myCalcField = pvt.CalculatedFields("Customer Savings %")

        **myCalcField = "=IF('Field1'=0,0,('Field2'/'Field3'))"
```

Comment: `Dim myCalcField As Excel.PivotField` - a calculated fields is just a regular field - it doesn't have a specific type. Use `myCalcField.Formula` to set the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something more like this:

```
Sub DEG()

    Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim aWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim pvt As Excel.PivotTable

    Set aWB = ActiveWorkbook
    For Each WS In aWB.Worksheets
        For Each pvt In WS.PivotTables

            On Error Resume Next

            pvt.PivotFields("Convert or Convert with DEG").CurrentPage = "Y"

            pvt.PivotFields("Select2").CurrentPage = "1"

            pvt.PivotFields("Top 20").CurrentPage = "Y"

            pvt.CalculatedFields.Item("Customer Savings %").Formula = _
                                  "=IF('Field1'=0,0,('Field2'/'Field3'))"
```

Comment: https://www.excelanytime.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=152:excel-pivot-tables-insert-calculated-fields-a-calculated-items-create-formulas-using-vba&catid=79&Itemid=475

Comment: Awesome. I appreciate you cleaning up my code too. For anyone interested in more info, I found the doc that describes more about the CalculatedFields methods  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.calculatedfields.item